# MAMP PHP7 Mongodb extension symbol not found

Tags: php, mongodb, ssl, laravel-5

I've installed PHP mongodb extension ver1.1.6 for PHP7. I'm using MAMP on OS X El Capitan.

I can connect to my mongo instance without SSL, but when I enable SSL I get

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _php_mongo_asn1_time_to_time_t
Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mongodb.so
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _php_mongo_asn1_time_to_time_t
Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mongodb.so
Expected in: flat namespace
```

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and jessengers/mongodb lib

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?